# highlight a word without affecting the structure of text

Tags: awk, sed, grep

```
$cat contents.txt

cat-1.15

cat-1.15

cat-1.15
cat-1.18
```

The above output has blank lines

`$cat contents.txt | grep cat`
results in the word cat being highlighted, but the resultant text is also merged, eliminating blank lines

```
cat-1.15
cat-1.15
cat-1.15
cat-1.18
```

How can I grep to highlight without grep affecting the text structure, so that the only difference is the grep term being highlighted ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU grep this can be accomplished with the `-z` option.

> -z, --null-data
>
> > Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.  Like the -Z or --null
> >                   option, this option can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.

Also this is a [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).  You can specify an input file with grep.

```
$ grep --color cat contents.txt
cat-1.15
cat-1.15
cat-1.15
cat-1.18
$ grep --color -z cat contents.txt
cat-1.15

cat-1.15

cat-1.15
cat-1.18
```

Comment: Note that this will try to read the whole file into memory. If it is big, a big chunk of memory will be used.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is to provide two patterns to `grep`: one will be the actual pattern or term to be searched for, and the second one will be an empty string.

```
$ grep --color -e 'cat' -e '' testfile.txt
cat-1.15

cat-1.15

cat-1.15
cat-1.18
```

The `-e` option is used for specify multiple patterns. From the manual:

> `-e PATTERN`, `--regexp=PATTERN`
>
> Use PATTERN as  the  pattern.   This  can  be  used  to  specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).  (`-e` is specified by POSIX.)

You can also combine those patterns as a single extended regular expression, if required:

```
$ grep --color -E 'cat|' testfile.txt
cat-1.15

cat-1.15

cat-1.15
cat-1.18
```

Also, you can simply add another pattern to the list if you need to highlight more than one keyword.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more possibilities with grep:

grep for 0 or more instances of `cat`:

```
grep --color '\(cat\)*' contents.txt
```

grep for `cat` **or** the empty string:

```
grep -E --color 'cat|' contents.txt
```

(The -E specifies extended regex syntax.  `egrep` may be used instead of `grep -E` here.)

---

Alternatively you can use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html) to do the colourization manually using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
red='\c[[1;31m'
default='\c[[0m'
sed "s/cat/${red}cat${default}/g" contents.txt
```

Here the `red` and `default` shell variables are conveniences only - their values could just as well be placed inline in the sed expression.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below command

```
sed -r "/cat/{N;s/^$/&=/}" filename


awk '{if(((length($1)>3)&& ($1 ~ /cat/))||($0~/^$/)){print $0}}' filename
```

Comment: How do these highlight the output?